# SSL Handshake Exception on TCP Outbound Gateway

Tags: spring-integration, tcpclient

We are attempting to make a socket connection to a client using Spring TCP Outbound Gateway. The connection requires TLS V1.2 Support and we have received a set of certificates that I have added to a keystore file I created. I have also enabled the DefaultSSLHandhsake support on my connection factory.

This code works fine on a few machines but gives a Messaging exception (SSL handshake, Hostname or IP is undefined) on another set of machines. The client in this case has confirmed they do not have any firewall/network restrictions at their end to prevent traffic from certain locations i.e. as long as the cert is present the connection should succeed. Below is the sample spring application I am using as a test

```
package Signature.Signature;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.dsl.TcpClientConnectionFactorySpec;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnectionSupport;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration

public class FamulusClient {
    
    
    private String host;


    private int port;

    private int connectionPoolSize;

    
    private int timeOut;

    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public static final CustomSerializerDeserializer SERIALIZER = new CustomSerializerDeserializer();

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }
 

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666);
            serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        System.out.println("before");
        
        try {
        SpringApplication.run(FamulusClient.class, args);
        //PrimeTcpClientGateway myBean = applicationContext.getBean(PrimeTcpClientGateway.class);
        //chcGate.send("Hello".getBytes());
        System.out.println("after");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done");

    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNioClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory("test.connect.changehealthcare.com", 9807);
        
        //TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory("claim-dev.famulushealth.com", 5555);
        //tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
        //tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new CustomStxHeaderLengthSerializer());
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new CustomStxHeaderLengthSerializer());
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setTcpNioConnectionSupport(connectionSupport());
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(3000);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        //ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory threadAffinityClientConnectionFactory = new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory);

        return tcpNioClientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="outboundChannel")
    public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="replyChannel")
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler outboundGateway(TcpNioClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
         //tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
          tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(3000);
          tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(3000);
          tcpOutboundGateway.setSendTimeout(3000);
          //tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }
    
    /*@Bean
    public DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport connectionSupport() {
        DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport
                ("file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts",
                "file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts", "changeit", "changeit");
        //sslContextSupport.setProtocol("SSL");
        //sslContextSupport.
        DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport tcpNioConnectionSupport =
                new DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport(sslContextSupport);
        return tcpNioConnectionSupport;
    }*/
    

    @Bean
    public DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport connectionSupport() {
        DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport
                ("classpath:myKeystore",
                "classpath:nyKeystore", "changeit", "changeit");
        //sslContextSupport.setProtocol("SSL");
        //sslContextSupport.
        DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport tcpNioConnectionSupport =
                new DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport(sslContextSupport);
        return tcpNioConnectionSupport;
    }
    

    /*@Bean
    public TcpNetConnectionSupport connectionSupport() {
        DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport
                ("file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts",
                "file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.3.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts", "changeit", "changeit");
        //sslContextSupport.setProtocol("SSL");
        //sslContextSupport.
        
        return sslContextSupport;
    }*/
    
    
    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outboundChannel")
    public interface CHCGateway {

        byte[] send(byte[] message);

    }
    
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(CHCGateway gate) {
        return args -> {
            String b1Message ="0484032   000060                       610144D0B1D0TEST    1011199999990     20220418FAMULUS   AM04C2123456789C61C90CCTESTCDTESTAM01C419000501C52C701CATESTCBCLAIMCM123 ANY STREETCNFORT WORTHCOTXCP76102CX01CY0000000004X01AM07EM1D27418529E103D768727010001U701C800D300D5030D61D81DE20210210DF06DI00DJ4E70000540000EU0028MLAM11D90183936{DN01DQ0183936{DU0183936{AM032JDIANE2K2160 TEST ADDY2MFORT WORTH2NTX2P76107EZ01DB1234567891DRTESTPHY";
            //String testmsg ="hello from client";
            byte[] resp = gate.send(b1Message.getBytes());
            String chcResp = new String(resp);
            System.out.println("resp.."+chcResp);
            //Thread.sleep(5_000);
        };
    }
    

}
```

Exception StackTrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Send Failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Socket closed during SSL Handshake, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[489], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@24043ec5, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@24043ec5, id=04d8f0a2-1fd8-45a1-146d-351215eb1eb7, timestamp=1651775076900}]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.send(TcpNioConnection.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:226)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:513)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:661)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:586)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:553)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:542)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.send(Unknown Source)
    at Signature.Signature.FamulusClient.lambda$0(FamulusClient.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Socket closed during SSL Handshake
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioSSLConnection$SSLChannelOutputStream.waitForHandshakeData(TcpNioSSLConnection.java:433)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioSSLConnection$SSLChannelOutputStream.doClientSideHandshake(TcpNioSSLConnection.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioSSLConnection$SSLChannelOutputStream.doWrite(TcpNioSSLConnection.java:365)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection$ChannelOutputStream.write(TcpNioConnection.java:633)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.send(TcpNioConnection.java:164)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: May we also see a stack trace for the error you mention?

Comment: Use `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to debug SSL problems. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Added the exception stacktrace. Also the code works when we update the version of the spring boot dependency in our pom.xml file. With version 2.5.2 we get the above exception but with version 2.0.3 we can make a connection    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <!--   <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version> -->
       
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    </parent>

Comment: OK. to make it clear. Do you mean that this works with Spring Boot `2.0.3`, but does not with `2.5.2`? Why exactly those versions, but not something latest: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn? What are your investigation after Gary's suggestion with the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` ?

Comment: We get the same exception by using the latest spring boot version i.e. 2.6.7

Comment: On updating the spring boot version the root cause of the SSL exception is as ERROR 55437 --- [pool-1-thread-2] o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNioSSLConnection          : Exception on Read stg.connect.changehealthcare.com:9807:62786:68b3a5b4-e955-4b84-8ed4-77cf37a1073e null

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.base/sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(IPAddressUtil.java:49) ~[na:na]

Comment: We are now able to reproduce consistently across all environments. On using latest spring-boot versions we are getting the exception ava.base/sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(IPAddressUtil.java:49) on the host DNS i.e "stg.connect.changehealthcare.com". If I revert to version 2.0.3RELEASE everything works as expected. Seems on latest versions it cannot parse to IPV4 address using the same DNS. Is there a property I can set to bypass the parsing ?